# What happens when a .NET application is scaled down in AWS App Runner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-app-runner

I know, with AWS Lambdas, you really can't start long-running tasks in the background, for a variety of reasons. I've seen indications that App Runner might be slightly better at that sort of thing. But I haven't been able to find documentation about the details of App Runner instance shutdowns.

Suppose when responding to a request, an ASP.NET Core app [queues up a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) which might take up to a minute to complete, and then the app returns a response to the original request.

Now suppose App Runner starts scaling down this application: it stops sending new requests to the instance it has selected to shut down. After all the current requests have finished, does App Runner send a command to invoke IHostedService CancellationTokens? If so, how long a grace period is the application given to complete before it gets forcefully shut down?

Does App Runner use the same strategy [used by ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/), where it sends a `SIGTERM`, waits a period of time, and sends a `SIGKILL` to the app? If so, is that period of time configurable?

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QUEwbKE9jbTCyLn7OnqGhOrA/app-runner-scaling-for-background-service
Does this address your concern? Seems like the service is only suitable for respond/request type of application

Comment: @qkhanhpro: That doesn't _quite_ fit my concern: I'm thinking of an app that _does_ have request/response behaviors, but sometimes the request results in a separate fire-and-forget action which may complete after the response is returned. Besides the example I gave, imagine I'm producing Kafka events using a client that batches and sends requests on a background thread. I want to know whether the application will get a shutdown signal and have a long enough grace period to exit gracefully before getting forcefully terminated.

Comment: Isn't that what the post described, you spawn another action that is not bound to the request / a background action, App Runner do not account for that orphaned action and they do not guarantee any behaviour.

Comment: @qkhanhpro The post says, "Some of the services are just background jobs meaning there will be no incoming requests to those services specifically....Does the fact that the instance get CPU throttled mean that I will not get proper instances and App Runner is not capable of running a service that does not serve http requests?" They're specifically asking about a service that does not receive requests, whereas I'm asking about a service that *does* receive requests, but sometimes has short-lived background work resulting from those requests (and grows proportionately to those requests).

Comment: Someone has linked to your question here: https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/96#issuecomment-1825234056 - can't you just practically try this?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: It's unclear which "this" you're asking for me to try. [Having a lambda invoke an endpoint that doesn't return until the background task completes](https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/96#issuecomment-1289440864)? [Switching to ECS](https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/96#issuecomment-1468481128)? There are plenty of options, but I'm asking in order to know what's required. If de-provisioning instances signals a shutdown to the app and gives it a reasonable grace period to clean up its work, I don't need to create more complicated workarounds.

Comment: Should've used a semicolon, sorry. I mean, you can't practically try what you describe and know the answer from experience? I doubt anyone other than the core App Runner team can give you an authoritative answer on this.

Comment: I'm not currently using App Runner, but I'm preparing for a project in which we may use it. I was hoping somebody can provide these details, either based on their own real-world experience, or because they work on the App Runner team, or because they're simply better at googling things than I am. But if not, I will run an experiment and report back here.